# Can I sort rows between two or more different tables in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting multiple tables with tablesorter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143623/sorting-multiple-tables-with-tablesorter)

I have five tables generated dynamically each have one row and i want to sort these tables. I dont want to combine these rows as a single table due to some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one **[jquery.tablesorter.min.js](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)**